# How to input() value longer than 4095 characters?

Tags: python-3.x, input

I'm trying to `input()` a string containing a large paste of JSON.

(Why I'm pasting a large blob of json is outside the scope of my question, but please believe me when I say I have a not-completely-idiotic reason!)

However, `input()` only grabs the first 4095 characters of the paste, for reasons described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18018473/8753669).

My code looks roughly like this:

```
import json

foo = input()
json.loads(foo)
```

When I paste a blob of JSON that's longer than 4095 characters, `json.loads(foo)` raises an error. (The error varies based on the specifics of how the JSON gets cut off, but it invariably fails one way or another because it's missing the final `}`.)

I looked at [the documentation for `input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), and it made no mention of anything that looked useful for this issue. No flags to input in non-canonical mode, no alternate `input()`-style functions to handle larger inputs, etc.

Is there a way to be able to paste large inputs successfully? This would make my tool's workflow way less janky than having to paste into a file, save it somewhere, and then pass the file's location into the script.

Comment: Is it 4095 characters all on one line?

Comment: you seem to have found the reason in the link you mentioned. So it has nothing to do with python

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It has to do with Python, because I was hoping to avoid an out-of-band workaround (like making the buffer size something stupid-huge, or using a different language).

Comment: using a different language doesn't seem to cut it either. You can always send the commands to change terminal behaviour from python with system calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python has to follow the terminal rules. But you could use a system call from python to change terminal behaviour and change it back (Linux):

```
import subprocess,json

subprocess.check_call(["stty","-icanon"])
result = json.loads(input())
subprocess.check_call(["stty","icanon"])
```

Alternately, consider trying to get an indented `json` dump from your provider that you can read line by line, then decode.

```
data = "".join(sys.stdin.readlines())
result = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: The stdlib interface for POSIX style tty control is [termios](https://docs.python.org/3/library/termios.html).  I guess canon would be a combo of `termios.VERASE` and `termios.VKILL` flags.

Comment: that would be better to avoid 2 system calls I agree.