# iPython paste limit of one screen?

Tags: python, linux, ipython

I often like to debug by pasting hunks of code into my ipython terminal by just highlighting and middle clicking it (linux environment). Just now I'm noticing a limitation where it will only take in one screen full of code (one terminal with no scrolling).  It's really weird because it doesn't truncate the code at the end but rather throws away the beginning such that the last stuff pasted is at the bottom of the terminal.  And it really is fixed at one screen full because if I zoom out the terminal so there are more visible lines, it will accept more. Anyone know the source of this or how to fix it?  I know I can source files and other stuff, but I like my current work flow.

Comment: I think this is a terminal emulator limit, not iPython.

Comment: You may even be hitting a limit in the kernel's TTY implementation -- see [Linux terminal input reading user input from terminal truncating lines at 4095 character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015137). We'd need more details to identify exactly which limiting factor is the relevant one in the specific use case at hand.

Comment: I can paste as much as I want in vi.  Is this different somehow?

Comment: it works with arbitrary code size for me - it will _display_ truncated text, so that scrolling up shows garbage, when pasting, but will "see" and accept all code pasted.

Comment: I'm nowhere near 4095 in any case.  In experimenting, it really is one screen.  If I shrink the terminal to a few lines, I'll get a few lines.  I now believe it actually is pasted and in memory, but when I scroll up to look, the rendering doesn't work properly to show it.  If I up-arrow, I can get it to reappear one line at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works with arbitrary code size - it will display truncated text past the terminal size, so scrolling up will show garbage, when pasting, but it will ingest all pasted, and process it as Python code content correctly.

Just to be doubly sure, despite that been my experience, I just tried it here with iPython version 8.21.0, with a 100-line generated file creating numbered variables, and they where all created, despite not being displayed after pasted.

And, of course, if you want to edit the pasted content inside iPython itself, "walking" into it with the up arrow will display all pasted content correctly and allow editing.