# how to change the python's stdin buffer size?

Tags: python, linux, stdin

I use python's stdin to recv message from other process

but want to change the stdin buff size for fast recv message

I know the subprocee can set the stdin buff when open a subprocess process

but One of my process is a c process whice send message

the other is a python process which recv message

how can i change the stdin buff size in python?

my host is a linux machine..

Comment: That is a beautiful poem.

Comment: @jdi Thanks for the good laugh !

Answer (score 0):

From [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3670470/1287112):

> You can completely remove buffering from stdin/stdout by using python's -u flag:
>
> ```
> -u     : unbuffered binary stdout and stderr (also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x)
>          see man page for details on internal buffering relating to '-u'
> ```
>
> and the man page clarifies:
>
> ```
>   -u     Force stdin, stdout and stderr to  be  totally  unbuffered.   On
>          systems  where  it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr in
>          binary mode.  Note that there is internal  buffering  in  xread-
>          lines(),  readlines()  and  file-object  iterators ("for line in
>          sys.stdin") which is not influenced by  this  option.   To  work
>          around  this, you will want to use "sys.stdin.readline()" inside
>          a "while 1:" loop.
> ```

Other than that, it is not (well or widely) supported.

Comment: If you're just cribbing from another answer, the correct thing to do is to mark the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry about that, I couldn't find the button to do so.