# taking multiline input with sys.stdin

Tags: python, sys

I have the following function:

```
def getInput():
    # define buffer (list of lines)
    buffer = []
    run = True
    while run:
        # loop through each line of user input, adding it to buffer
        for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
            if line == 'quit\n':
                run = False
            else:
                buffer.append(line.replace('\n',''))
    # return list of lines
    return buffer
```

which is called in my function takeCommands(), which is called to actually run my program.

However, this doesn't do anything. I'm hoping to add each line to an array, and once a line == 'quit' it stops taking user input. I've tried both `for line in sys.stdin.readlines()` and `for line sys.stdin`, but neither of them register any of my input (I'm running it in Windows Command Prompt). Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: the problem is `'quit' != 'quit\n'`

Comment: Notice that each `line` will have a `'\n'` on the end, so you won't ever hit the `run = False` condition.

Comment: I have changed my original post to what I tried next. Still doesn't register any input or ever quit waiting for input.

Comment: The problem with your code (as currently posted) is that you call `sys.stdin.readlines()`. That returns a `list` of lines. Obviously it can't make that `list` until it has all the lines, which means it can't return until you close standard input. The solution to that is to just… not call `readlines()`. It's certainly possible that you have a _new_ problem after solving that one, just as you had a new problem after fixing the one JBernardo showed, but that doesn't mean this isn't a problem you need to fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, took your code out of the function and ran some tests.

```
import sys
buffer = []
while run:
    line = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
    if line == 'quit':
        run = False
    else:
        buffer.append(line)

print buffer
```

Changes:

- Removed the 'for' loop
- Using 'readline' instead of 'readlines'
- strip'd out the '\n' after input, so all processing afterwards is much easier.

Another way:

```
import sys
buffer = []
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
    if line == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        buffer.append(line)
print buffer
```

Takes out the 'run' variable, as it is not really needed.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `itertools.takewhile` for this:

```
import sys
import itertools
print list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x.strip() != 'quit', sys.stdin))
```

Another way to do this would be to use the 2-argument `iter` form:

```
print list(iter(raw_input,'quit'))
```

This has the advantage that `raw_input` takes care of all of the line-buffering issues and it will strip the newlines for you already -- But it will loop until you run out of memory if the user forgets to add a `quit` to the script.

Both of these pass the test:

```
python test.py <<EOF
foo
bar
baz
quit
cat
dog
cow
EOF
```

Comment: using the two-argument form of `iter` is usually simpler than takewhile

Comment: @JBernardo -- They're pretty much equivalent (if I remember correctly), but I find `takewhile` to be much easier to understand since it does only 1 thing.  with `iter`, the reader needs to recognize that you're using the 2 argument form and then they need to remember how that is different than the 1 argument form etc. etc.  Sure you have to type a little more -- and import itertools, but I find that a small price to pay for the extra explicitness.

Comment: Unfortunately this is for a homework assignment, and they specifically requested using standard input and output to make their mass testing easier.

Comment: @Jakemmarsh -- You might be running into [line-buffering problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670323/setting-smaller-buffer-size-for-sys-stdin)

Comment: @JBernardo -- Added a `iter` example too.

Comment: @Jakemmarsh: `raw_input` reads from standard input. For that matter, the `takewhile` version of this is clearly using `stdin` in the same way your program is (except that it doesn't call `readlines()`, which is the problem with your code). So… what makes you think that violates the prof's request to use standard input?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple separate problems with this code:

```
while run:
    # loop through each line of user input, adding it to buffer
    for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
        if line == 'quit':
            run = False
```

---

First, you have an inner loop that won't finish until all lines have been processed, even if you type "quit" at some point. Setting `run = False` doesn't break out of that loop. Instead of quitting as soon as you type "quit", it will keep going until it's looked at all of the lines, and *then* quit if you typed "quit" at any point.

You can fix this one pretty easily by adding a `break` after the `run = False`.

---

But, with or without that fix, if you *didn't* type "quit" during that first time through the outer loop, since you've already read all input, there's nothing else to read, so you'll just keep running an empty inner loop over and over forever that you can never exit.

You have a loop that means "read and process all the input". You want to do *that* exactly once. So, what should the outer loop be? It should not be anyway; the way to do something once is to not use a loop. So, to fix this one, get rid of `run` and the `while run:` loop; just use the inner loop.

---

Then, if you type "quit", `line` will actually be `"quit\n"`, because `readlines` does not strip newlines.

You fix this one by either testing for `"quit\n"`, or `strip`ping the lines.

---

Finally, even if you fix all of these problems, you're still waiting forever before doing anything. `readlines` returns a `list` of lines. The only way it can possibly do that is by reading all of the lines that will ever be on `stdin`. You can't even start looping until you've read all those lines.

When standard input is a file, that happens when the file ends, so it's not *too* terrible. But when standard input is the Windows command prompt, the command prompt never ends.* So, this takes forever. You don't get to start processing the list of lines, because it takes forever to wait for the list of lines.

The solution is to not use `readlines()`. Really, there is never a good reason to call `readlines()` on anything, `stdin` or not. Anything that `readlines` works on is *already* an iterable full of lines, just like the `list` that `readlines` would give you, except that it's "lazy": it can give you the lines one at a time, instead of waiting and giving you all of them at once. (And even if you really need the list, just do `list(f)` instead of `f.readlines()`.)

So, instead of `for line in sys.stdin.readlines():`, just do `for line in sys.stdin:` (Or, better, replace the explicit loop completely and use a sequence of iterator transformations, as in mgilson's answer.)

---

The fixes JBernardo, Wing Tang Wong, etc. proposed are all correct, and necessary. The reason none of them fixed your problems is that if you have 4 bugs and fix 1, your code still doesn't work. That's exactly why "doesn't work" isn't a useful measure of anything in programming, and you have to debug what's actually going wrong to know whether you're making progress.

---

* I lied a bit about `stdin` never being finished. If you type a control-Z (you may or may not need to follow it with a return), then `stdin` is finished. But if your assignment is to make it quit as soon as the user types "quit"< turning in something that only quits when the user types "quit" and then return, control-Z, return again probably won't be considered successful.

Answer (score 0):

The following works (on Linux, at least).

```
import pathlib

pathlib.Path("/proc/self/fd/0").read_text()
```

Above, `/proc/self/fd/0` means "stdin".

Press `Ctrl + D` to end the multi-line input.