# stdin.read() does not read any input

Tags: python

The program as shown below runs without pausing to take my input. If I uncomment the line with `inpt = input()` function and comment out the `inpt  = sys.stdin.read()` - it behaves as expected: waits for my input then terminates.

What did I do wrong? In case that matters, IDE is Spider.

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #inpt = input()
    inpt = sys.stdin.read()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133224/reading-from-sys-stdin-ending-user-input-with-return