# How can I read redirected/piped data?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have log files located in:

`/mfs/log/scribe/clicklog/*/clicklog_current`

which I want to process in realtime with Python, so I created a `transform.py` file:

`tail -f /mfs/log/scribe/clicklog/*/clicklog_current | grep 'pattern' | ./transform.py`

in `tranform.py`:

```
def process_line(line):
    print real_process(line)
```

the problem is: How can I call `process_line` everytime there is a new line from `stdin`?

Comment: You could mimic ```tail -f``` with a python equivalent.  Take a look at follow.py,  cofollow.py, and copipe.py at [A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever redirection or piping happening, the standard input stream will be set to that. So you can directly read from [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdin), like this

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    process_line(line)
```

If the buffering bites you, you can adjust/disable the input buffering, like mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3670470/1903116)

**Reduce the buffering size:**

```
import os
import sys

for line in os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'r', 100):
    process_line(line)
```

Now it buffers only 100 bytes max.

**Disable the buffering:**

Quoting the official documentation,

**[`-u`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u)**

> Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered. On systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr in binary mode.
>
> Note that there is internal buffering in `file.readlines()` and File Objects (`for line in sys.stdin`) which is not influenced by this option. To work around this, you will want to use `file.readline()` inside a `while 1: loop`.

Comment: this works, but occasionally got: `tail: log.txt: file truncated`

Comment: I think the log.txt file is getting cleared. Do you have log rotation or something like that in place?

Comment: nope, I just created `log.txt`, open it in vim, run `tail -f log.txt | python -u transform.py`. then input lines in `log.txt` and save it to see the output.

Comment: Whenever you save the file, vim might decide to internally clear the file.

Answer (score 1):

The [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) library may be able to do what you're looking for.

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    if line == '': pass
    process_line(line)
```

Comment: fileinput doesn't do blocking when an input file is open

Comment: In that case, correcting now to the best of my abilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the `tail -f` part completely by using [`watchdog`](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) and `grep` by using the `re` module (although in this case, you don't even need that as your search criteria can be written as a simple membership test).

Here is a simple example (modified from the documentation) that would do what you require:

```
import sys
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.handlers import FileSystemEventHandler

class WatchFiles(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def process_file(self, event):
        """
        does stuff the file
        """
        with open(event.src_path, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                if 'pattern' in line:
                   do_stuff(line)

    def on_modified(self, event):
        self.process_file(event)

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process_file(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(WatchFiles(), path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

This way, your application is not only more portable but all parts of it are self-contained.

Comment: How do we ensure we wrote the partial processed output if we Ctrl-C the python?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.utils.BaseThread.on_thread_stop).

Comment: BurhanKhalid there's more to it than that. You want to be flushing the output intermittently (how often?)

Comment: @smci please create a new question with the details of your scenario.