# Bidrectional node/python communication

Tags: python, node.js, ipc

I'm trying to implement simple bidirectional communication between node and a spawned Python process.

Python:

```
import sys
for l in sys.stdin:
    print "got: %s" % l
```

Node:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('python', ['-u', 'ipc.py']);
child.stdout.on('data', function(data){console.log("stdout: " + data)});

var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    console.log(i);
    child.stdin.write("i = " + i++ + "\n");
}, 1000);
```

Using `-u` on Python forces unbuffered I/O so I would expect to see the output (I've also tried `sys.stdout.flush()`) but don't. I know I can use `child.stdout.end()` but that prevents me from writing data later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python code crashes with `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` at line

```
print "got: " % l
```

You ought to write

```
print "got: %s" % l
```

---

You can see the errors that Python outputs by doing:

```
var child = spawn('python', ['-u', 'ipc.py'],
    { stdio: [ 'pipe', 'pipe', 2 ] });
```

on Node.js, that is, pipe only standard output but let the standard error go to Node's stderr.

---

Even with these fixes, and even accounting for `-u` the [`sys.stdin.__iter__` will be buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670323/setting-smaller-buffer-size-for-sys-stdin). To work around it, use `.readline` instead:

```
for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    print "got: %s" % line
    sys.stdout.flush()
```