# How can I take input from a pipe in Python and immediately output it?

Tags: python, pipe, stdout, stdin, io-redirection

I would like to write a program that can take input piped to it, manipulate it, and output it immediately.  It seems that no matter what various things I try (using `stdout.write` rather than `print`, explicitly flushing `stdout`, setting `stdin` to be unbuffered), the output seems to be delayed until the input program is closed.

Example input script:

```
import sys
import time

sys.stdout.write('1\n')
sys.stdout.flush()

time.sleep(3)

sys.stdout.write('2\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Example output script:

```
import sys
import time

for line in sys.stdin:

    print time.time()

    sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

If I run this:

```
python input.py | python output.py
```

I get something like this:

```
1428023794.99
1
1428023794.99
2
```

Clearly the lines are making it to the second program at the same time.  I've also tried running the second python script with the `-u` flag to [unbuffer stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670323/setting-smaller-buffer-size-for-sys-stdin), but get the same output.

How can I make my program pulling the text from `stdin` output the text immediately?

Comment: I bet your shell (bash?) is buffering the pipe.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28919832/625914)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/8188

Answer (score 0):

I'm piping out crontab errors to Slack channels using the following code:

```
import os
import sys

def get_stdin():
  #
  # This will get stdin piped input *if exists*
  #

  with os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb', buffering=0) as stdin:
    if not stdin.seekable():
      return [_.decode('utf-8') for _ in stdin.readlines()]

stdin = get_stdin()
print("Found content:", stdin)
```

The biggest challenge I had here, was:

- If there's stdin piped content - code worked just fine
- If there's nothing passed to the script - script hang and wait for input + (CTRL+D)

That was solved by checking `stdin.seekable()` if there's any content pending to be read or not ....

Tested on both:

```
$ cat file.txt | slack.py   # stdin=True
$ ./slack.py --help         # stdin=False
```

Comment: "That was solved by checking stdin.seekable() if there's any content pending to be read or not" - `seekable` has nothing to do with whether there's data available to read.

Comment: Check and see ... there is. lowering the only answer in 8 years - did you even tried it ? I can guess it's because that when you have data pending - it initialize stdin with `IOTextWrapper` and if you don't have content then it waits for input and hangs until CTRL+D - it initialize it with `IOBufferWrapper` .. this is why `seekable` works on one but not the other if you have different suggestion - please specify, i couldn't find such, including the comments in the original question.

Comment: There is no such thing as IOBufferWrapper or IOTextWrapper. `io.TextIOWrapper` and `io.BufferedReader` exist, but the way `sys.stdin` is initialized has nothing to do with whether data is available. Also, I *did* try this, and it completely failed - `./slack.py --help` hangs, because `sys.stdin` is reading from terminal input, which is unseekable. (Also you forgot the shebang line, which I had to fix.)

Comment: If you check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seekable), you'll find that `seekable` is documented as "Return True if the stream supports random access. If False, seek(), tell() and truncate() will raise OSError." It's a check for whether you're reading from something you can freely jump ahead or back in, like a file, or something you can't do that with, like a pipe or a tty.

Comment: @user2357112 I got the function - from the docs. run every function i saw there. and this the pipe is converted to a "file"-like object (`os.fdopen` ) this is why `seekable` works. if you can't jump - there's nothing there. for me, piping works just fine in both cases ( when we have content and when we don't (use just args) ) and i've setup my cronjob to pass all unexpected content to my Slack channel this way - if someone else wants to try it out - great.

Comment: @user2357112 In regards to `There is no such thing as IOBufferWrapper or IOTextWrapper` your explanation that comes afterwards is exactly what I explained in the answer. the `readlines()` that we run cause the script to hang. so how in the code you can *check* if you have pending content or not ? this is what i was able to overcome - do you have another option or not ?! that was my first question. and I didn't forgot the "shabang" - I provided a code snippet, i had no intention of adding it as it's not important, so there's nothing to "fix"

Comment: Some people ... god, how I hate SO sometimes. Thanks for the answer @RickyLevi, this gave me a decent pointer