# python - reading stdin and doing code before reading next line

Tags: python, stdin

I have code in python that looks like this:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line + "END"
```

I read that this iterates over stdin line by line, but honestly the command line output makes me think it's reading all of stdin and then iterating line by line; it's printing data, stopping, then printing more. I tested this by making a counter like so:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    print i
    i+=1
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

It would stop printing at 96, then at 218, etc., each for about half a second, before printing a whole bunch more numbers at the same time.

Is there a way of iterating over lines that executes the things in the loop before reading the next line?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I'm streaming data into a WebSocket with python in the middle of a bash program and the network (python is the client and is just forwarding messages).

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670323/setting-smaller-buffer-size-for-sys-stdin