# Pipe between python scripts

Tags: python, bash, pipe

I have a simple script that reads values from a device and outputs them via `print`, and another script, which listens on stdin and interprets each number. The device outputs one number each second. Surprisingly, piping the scripts on my ubuntu box does not work. However, if the first script is made not to read from the device but generate random numbers as fast as it can, the second script successfully receives the data.

Below is a simplified example of my situation.

**print.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import time
import sys

while True:
    time.sleep(1)  # without this everything works
    print "42"
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

**read.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys

while True:
    for str in sys.stdin:
        print str
```

Command line invocation:

```
vorac@laptop:~/test$ ./print.py | ./read.py
```

---

Here is the end result. The first script reads from the device and the second graphs the data in two separate time frames (what is shown are random numbers).

[image]

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3670323/5128464) might be interesting for you

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: I just added `newin = os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'r', 0);
sys.stdin = newin` to `read.py` and nothing has changed. I would strongly prefer to resolve this programatically and keep the invocation of the scripts simple.

Comment: Why don't you do both in the same script?

Comment: @MKesper, this is a program for reading, logging and presentation of temperature data. Being able to use the modules independently seems like a good feature - you could just listen to the device, or just plot some random data, or run the interruptable logger on some other data.

Comment: @Vorac easily solved by making each module a generator, or a separate function, or some such thing. That being said, having separate programs that each do a small task is in line with the UNIX philosophy. But in that case you could also use shell scripts or standard UNIX tools like `cat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, now that is a tricky problem. It happens because the iterator method for `sys.stdin` (which is [`xreadlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.xreadlines)) is buffered. In other words, when your loop implicitly calls `next(sys.stdin)` to get the next line of input, [Python tries to read](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#L2255) from the real under-the-hood standard input stream until its internal buffer is full, and only once the buffer is full does it proceed through the body of the loop. The [buffer size is 8 kilobytes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#L2321), so this takes a while.

You can see this by decreasing the time delay in the `sleep()` call to `0.001` or some such value, depending on the capabilities of your system. If you hit the time just right, you'll see nothing for a few seconds, and then a whole block of `42`s come out all at once.

To fix it, use [`sys.stdin.readline()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline), which is unbuffered.

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    print line
```

You might also want to strip off the trailing newline before printing it, otherwise you'll get double line breaks. Use `line.rstrip('\n')`, or just `print line,` to suppress the extra newline that gets printed.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your read.py and it worked for me :), you forget to `.readline()` from `stdin`.

```
import sys
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line:
        print line.strip()
    else:
        continue
```

Output is :

```
$ python write.py | python read.py 
42
42
42
42
42
42
42
```

Comment: I think `readLine()` is important, time is useless, i was checking something else here ... corrected.