# How to run two python codes in two systems

Tags: python

I have two codes in python language in two systems. The first code must be run then its output will be used as the input of the second code on another system. How I can transfer data between these two codes?

Comment: This is quite a broad question. Look up the flask framework to turn the second script into a server. The first script can convert its data into json and send it over the network.

Answer (score 0):

In case you would need to use output of one script as input of another, but on a same system that would be nice example for usage of pipelines (example can be checked on next link: [Pipe between python scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608344/pipe-between-python-scripts))

But as far as I understood you, you have 2 separate systems, which means you will need sockets for cross-system communication. Very basic example of server/client communication can be found on next link: [Basic Python client socket example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749341/basic-python-client-socket-example)

If applications on both systems are having other tasks as well, note that you will have to implement listener in separate thread, so for that you will most likely need basic example of threading in python: [How to use threading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python)

Good luck!