# python: tail file in background

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to start a background process to tail a file, then read from the output so far on demand, while continuing to tail the file.  I've tried a few things using `subprocess` but haven't been able to make it work.

Here's what I tried:

```
tail = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-f', 'file.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
reader = tail.stdout

#do stuff

output = reader.read()  #spins
```

I considered using `reader.readline()` manually, but I can't figure out how to terminate the loop, since there won't be an EOF.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/how-to-start-a-background-process-in-python) yet? It also leads to the doc that has other suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps pipe the data you want from outside of the process?  Feels like ages about but I had a simple script for debugging memcache, full thing is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670323/setting-smaller-buffer-size-for-sys-stdin  You would still need to ctrl+c to break the cycle.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's helpful.  That answer talks about starting a process and detaching it from the parent, but doesn't address reading the output of that process.  I don't need (or want) to detach the process, I just want it running in the background.

Comment: @David requiring a CTRL+C is a dealbreaker.  This needs to be fully automated and can't depend on user input.

Comment: One other idea, if you want to break a busy loop when there is no more data, what about tracking the time between reads.  After ever successful read you could reset a val like "last_read" and then check it on every cycle of a busy loop until it reaches some sort of time limit you defined?

Comment: @ewok have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python) ?

Comment: @idjaw That does it! thanks.