# Accepting keyboard input without requiring the Enter key

Tags: python

Basically in my code I have a bit where you have to click 1 then enter then 2 then enter and I want to make it so when I press 1 I don't have to click the enter button. So all I have to do is press 1 and then it will roll the dice.

I have done a quick research and can't seem to find how to / what to type in on the internet (if there is a specific thing I need to write)

```
def Game_Round1():
    while player1_dice1_round1_dice != "1":
        player1_dice1_round1_dice = input("Press 1 to roll dice!: ")
    else:
        player1_dice1_round1_answer = random.randint(1, 6)
        print("You rolled the first dice and the answer is: ", player1_dice1_round1_answer)    

    player1_dice2_round1_roll_start = input("Press 2 to roll dice 2: ")
    while player1_dice2_round1_roll_start != "2":
        player1_dice2_round1_roll_start = input("Press 2 to roll dice2!: ")
    else:
        player1_dice2_round1_answer = random.randint(1, 6)
        print("You rolled the second dice and the answer is: ", player1_dice2_round1_answer)

    p1_round1_answer = (player1_dice1_round1_answer + player1_dice2_round1_answer)

    odd_or_even_checker = p1_round1_answer % 2
    if odd_or_even_checker > 0:
        print("as your number is even you will loose 5  points ")
        p1_round1_answer -= 5
    else:
        print("as your number is even you will gain an extra 10 points ")
        p1_round1_answer += 10
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [raw\_input in python without pressing enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523174/raw-input-in-python-without-pressing-enter)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726138/disable-buffering-of-sys-stdin-in-python-3

Comment: @Thomas i've just tried using those sites and the code when I paste it into a new file, it does not work.

Comment: @Isma  i've just tried using those sites and the code when I paste it into a new file, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `readchar` package. The `readchar` method of this package will block the console and wait for only one character and then output this character.

```
import readchar

def Game_Round1():
    while player1_dice1_round1_dice != "1":
        player1_dice1_round1_dice = readchar.readchar("Press 1 to roll dice!: ")
    else:
        player1_dice1_round1_answer = random.randint(1, 6)
        print("You rolled the first dice and the answer is: ", player1_dice1_round1_answer)    

    player1_dice2_round1_roll_start = readchar.readchar("Press 2 to roll dice 2: ")
    while player1_dice2_round1_roll_start != "2":
        player1_dice2_round1_roll_start = input("Press 2 to roll dice2!: ")
    else:
        player1_dice2_round1_answer = random.randint(1, 6)
        print("You rolled the second dice and the answer is: ", player1_dice2_round1_answer)

    p1_round1_answer = (player1_dice1_round1_answer + player1_dice2_round1_answer)

    odd_or_even_checker = p1_round1_answer % 2
    if odd_or_even_checker > 0:
        print("as your number is even you will loose 5  points ")
        p1_round1_answer -= 5
    else:
        print("as your number is even you will gain an extra 10 points ")
        p1_round1_answer += 10
```