# Is there any way to detect key press in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

I am wanting to make a program with different responses when you press a key. Is there any way that you can detect a key press in Python?

The program is like when you press `0`, it will say `you pressed 0` and when you pressed `ctrl-c` it will say that you interrupted the program, so on.

Can you do this in a `while True:` loop as well?

Also, I don't want it to be like `input` and I am using Linux (I don't want to have to use `root`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a command line application
you should be able to do it with

```py
import sys
import termios
import tty
custom_messages = {'a': 'some other message'}
custom_messages['b'] = 'what?';
stdin = sys.stdin.fileno()
tattr = termios.tcgetattr(stdin)
try:
    tty.setcbreak(stdin, termios.TCSANOW)
    while True:
        char = sys.stdin.read(1)
        print(custom_messages.get(char, 'You pressed ' + char))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print('You interrupted')
  sys.exit() ## ?
finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(stdin, termios.TCSANOW, tattr)
```

I based my answer on [disabling buffering in stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726138/disable-buffering-of-sys-stdin-in-python-3)

Comment: Did you accidentally unnacepted it?

Comment: No, But can you do something like `if char == 'a': print('some other message') else: print('You pressed' +char)` ?

Comment: I was wishing for something like that.

Comment: Nevermind it works. Accept again.

Comment: Check the update, I used a dictionary to specify custom messages, better than having multiple if/else branches.