# How to pipe an online stream into a python script, and produce streaming output

Tags: python, bash, pipe

I have the below python script, which accepts text input, format it (to html) and produces output.

It works ok when piping a static text input. However, it freezes (or probably waits for some kind of EOF) when the input is a stream of text.

I would like it to stream the output, instead of waiting the text to finish.

**EDIT:**
It seems that I wasn't patient enough, and it waits on some buffer to fill before dumping the output. **Any idea on how to dump the output for every line**

Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Convert a piped in text input to html, while replacing file/path names with URLs
"""
import sys
import os
import re

def file_html(field):
    field = field.group()
    if os.path.isfile(field) or os.path.isdir(field):
        return """<a href="file://{0}"  target="_blank">{0}  </a>""".format(field)
    else:
        return field

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = '<p><tt>' + re.sub('/[^\s]*', file_html, line) + '</tt></p>'
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: The script looks fine.  How are you piping a stream of text into the script?  If I run, for example `curl  https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt | python yourscript.py` it works without hanging.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I wasn't patient enough, and it waits on some buffer to fill before dumping the output. Any idea on how to dump the output for every line

Comment: Thanks, indeed after my edit, this question became a duplicate. As a side note: only the following solution was relevant to my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18235323/2476373