# Using textfile as stdin in python under windows 7

Tags: python, windows, pipe, io-redirection

I'm a win7-user.

I accidentally read about redirections (like `command1 < infile > outfile`) in *nix systems, and then I discovered that [something similar can be done in Windows (link)](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true). And python is also can do something like this with pipes(?) or stdin/stdout(?).

I do not understand how this happens in Windows, so I have a question.

I use some kind of proprietary windows-program (.exe). This program is able to append data to a file.
For simplicity, let's assume that it is the equivalent of something like

```
while True:
    f = open('textfile.txt','a')
    f.write(repr(ctime()) + '\n')
    f.close()
    sleep(100)
```

**The question:**
Can I use this file (textfile.txt) as stdin?
I mean that the script (while it runs) should always (not once) handle all new data, ie

In the "never-ending cycle":

- The program (.exe) writes something.
- Python script captures the data and processes.

Could you please write how to do this in python, or maybe in win cmd/.bat or somehow else.

**This is insanely cool thing. I want to learn how to do it! :D**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly then you want to pipe output from one command to another.

This is normally done as such:

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

However, you say that your program only writes to files. I would double check the documentation to see if their isn't a way to get the command to write to stdout instead of a file.

If this is not possible then you can create what is known as a `named pipe`. It appears as a file on your filesystem, but is really just a buffer of data that can be written to and read from (the data is a stream and can only be read once). Meaning your program reading it will not finish until the program writing to the pipe stops writing and closes the "file". I don't have experience with named pipes on windows so you'll need to ask a new question for that. One down side of pipes is that they have a limited buffer size. So if there isn't a program reading data from the pipe then once the buffer is full the writing program won't be able to continue and just wait indefinitely until a program starts reading from the pipe.

An alternative is that on Unix there is a program called `tail` which can be set up to continuously monitor a file for changes and output any data as it is appended to the file (with a short delay.

```
tail --follow=textfile.txt --retry | mycmd 
# wait for data to be appended to the file and output new data to mycmd

cmd1 >> textfile.txt # append output to file
```

One thing to note about this is that `tail` won't stop just because the first command has stopped writing to the file. `tail` will continue to listen to changes on that file forever or until mycmd stops listening to `tail`, or until `tail` is killed (or "sigint-ed").

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command) has various answers on how to get a version of `tail` onto a windows machine.

Comment: No, it only writes to files. Also, as I wrote, it opens, writes line and closes file. I read many articles about pipes, and (if understand it right) EOF closes named pipe. Or not?

Comment: An EOF does not close a named pipe. It will continue to exist and let more date be written. The problem is that the program repeatedly opens and closes the file and it is possible that your python script will empty the pipe faster than your program fills it and thus think it has consumed all the input and then stop. In this case `tail` seems like the best option. Cygwin or MinGW with MSYS should work for you. http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open('textfile.txt', 'r')
for line in sys.stdin:
    process(line)
```

Comment: @akaRem do you mean that you want to get the data repeatedly? You can use sys.stdin.seek(0) to get the data again.

Comment: .exe opens file, writes text, closes file. And does this (for example) for 2 hours. I want to feed this data (in real-time) to my script's stdin or something similar.

Comment: I can't do anything with program (to say it not wtite file, but write to stdout), but I thought I could do something with OS I/O (to say it write to file and stdin of script).

Answer (score 0):

If the program writes to `textfile.txt`, you can't change that to redirect to `stdin` of your Python script unless you recompile the program to do so.

If you *were* to edit the program, you'd need to make it write to `stdout`, rather than a file on the filesystem. That way you can use the redirection operators to feed it into your Python script (in your case the `|` operator).

Assuming you can't do that, you could write a program that polls for changes on the text file, and consumes only the newly written data, by keeping track of how much it read the last time it was updated.

Comment: No, I bought it and I can't change it. I can write every new data item into new file (but it will spawn an army of txt) - it's bad. How about system locks about read/write in case when I periodically check and read?

Comment: It depends on how the program opens the file. It might block access from other processes, or it might permit access, you'll have to test yourself. If it blocks other processes from reading, then I'd just ignore `open()` errors and try again on the next poll.

Comment: And if it permits access, is it possible that script will be reading line(`'...\n'`) while program is printing (`'blah-blah\n'`) and it will read only part of line (`'blah-b'`)? (I'm not very familiar with how the outputtting to a file is executed)

Comment: Yes it is possible, so you'd need to treat what you read as a stream, e.g. read until you hit a '\n'

Comment: Is `readline()` ok? Do I need to close file (in python) before next loop or I can keep it open? If I keep it open, will the .exe can to write line?

Comment: I've never done this before, but I suspect you'd read until you hit a EOF, I'm not sure what would happen after that, but I'm interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `<` to direct the output of a file to a python script, that script receives that data on it's [`stdin` stream](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdin).

Simply read from `sys.stdin` to get that data:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    # do something with line
```

Comment: @akaRem: `sys.stdin` is closed and the loop ends.

Comment: Yes, but the idea is to keep loop and wait for a new line. :(

Comment: @akaRem: Then you need to pipe something to `stdin` that is not finite, doesn't close the stream.

Comment: @akaRem: Alternatively, you'd have to poll the textfile and read from the opened file every time it has changed, but then you cannot use `<` redirection. You could pipe the output of the other program straight into python instead, for example.

Comment: So the idea of piping degrades to simple polling the file?

Comment: @akaRem: Yes, if you need to pick up new data written to the file by another process then you need to poll.

Comment: how do you detect if anything was passed to stdin at all?  if nothing was passed by redirect the above code hangs

Comment: @Anentropic: Python can't control a redirect to stdin. If you have a process that keeps the pipe open and never writes, that's not something Python do anything about. You could, at most, add a timeout (with a signal).

Comment: I meant, what if you don't pipe in a file at all? `python -c "from sys import stdin; print stdin.readlines()" < mytext.txt` works... but this hangs: `python -c "from sys import stdin; print stdin.readlines()"`. I found this method http://stackoverflow.com/a/17735803/202168 (`stdin.isatty()` returns `False` if you have a file) ...does that seem a good way?

Comment: @Anentropic: you are still connecting Python to a pipe. That that pipe is in turn connected to your terminal is something Python can again do little about. Yes, detecting that case with `stdin.isatty()` is a way around that.