# How to pass file contents to a python script on windows

Tags: python, command-line, dos

I would like to pass the contents of a file along with some other parameters to a python script on windows.

On linux, I can do it like this:

```
less input.txt | my_script.py  > output.txt
```

On windows I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
more input.txt | python my_script.py  > output.txt
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use following command. It works both in Linux and Windows.

```
python my_script.py < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: For anyone concerned: the contents of the file is accessible via sys.stdin rather than sys.argv[n]. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581632/using-textfile-as-stdin-in-python-under-windows-7