# Determining if fileinput.input has any input?

Tags: python

I'm using Python's [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module to either read data from `stdin` or from files passed in as program arguments. That's fine and works well. The problem is I'd like the program to behave differently if there is no input. When there's nothing on `stdin` and no program arguments, `stdin` reads data from the console i.e. it becomes interactive. That is the state I'd like to detect. `fileinput` doesn't advertise any tools for helping here. There are methods to determine if the current line is a file or stream (e.g. [`isstdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.isstdin)).

Using [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17735803/4822566), and poking around the internals of `fileinput`, I've got something that works, but it relies on `FileInput._files` which feels like something I shouldn't be using:

```
import sys, fileinput

def has_lines():
    lines = fileinput.input()
    return (lines._files != ('-',) or not sys.stdin.isatty()), lines
#                 ^                                 ^
#                 |                                 |
# Concerned about referring to internals            |
#                                 Returns false if there's something in stdin

existing_input, lines = has_lines()
if existing_input:
    for line in lines:
        pass #Batch processing mode
else:
    pass #Interactive mode
```

Can I detect interactive mode without poking around the internals of a `FileInput` object?

Comment: "When there's nothing on `stdin` and no program arguments, `stdin` reads data from the console" - Input via the console is just as much `stdin` as `stdin` being connected to anything else (a file, a pipe to another process, etc.). Aside from the latency (which any old pipe to another process *might* exhibit), there is nothing unique about being connected to the console. I feel like you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040), because it usually shouldn't matter what `stdin` is connected to.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Perhaps I am asking the wrong question. I can see there are a few parts to the question. Determining if I'm on an interactive TTY is part of it, determining if there are files in the program arguments is another. I guess I the issue is between fileinput (which hides a bunch of implementation), and TTY input (which fileinput doesn't cater for out of the box).

Comment: To be clear, `fileinput` hides a bunch of implementation for a reason. It's intended for simple use cases (and to make Perl folks who love `while (<>) {` comfortable switching). If you're looking at digging into the messy details, it's a good chance your program should be implementing its own argument parsing and file opening/handling (e.g. with `argparse` to aid), so you have the control you need.

Comment: So, in your opinion, `fileinput` is the wrong tool for the job?