# How do I exit a program if no file is passed?

Tags: python

I have a program that needs input: program.py < test.txt

How would I make it so that the program will exit if it doesn't get a file input?

this is how I read the input:

```
def file():
    global index
    import sys


    tempo = sys.stdin.readlines()

    for element in tempo:

        if(index == 1):
            key_route.append(element.strip('\n').rstrip().lstrip().lower())
            index = 5
        else:
            routes.append(element.strip('\n').rstrip().lstrip().lower())
```

Comment: `if not temp: exit()`

Comment: Wanna post that as the answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if stdin has some data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762881/how-do-i-check-if-stdin-has-some-data)

Answer (score 0):

test if you have anything in temp:

```
if not temp: 
    exit()
```

Comment: it doesnt work, it just and waits for input by the looks of things

Comment: and you call `file()`?

Comment: `sys.stdin.readlines()` might indeed just halts execution until somthing becomes available, which could be none

Comment: yeah we call file

Comment: you could just ctrl-c it then or take a look at the duplicate question to work around the readlines or you can pass a path to the file as a argument and open it yourself in your program

Answer (score 0):

The following should do:

```
global index
import sys

def file():
    tempo = sys.stdin.readline()

    if not tempo.strip():
        sys.exit()

    for element in tempo:
        if(index == 1):
            key_route.append(element.strip('\n').rstrip().lstrip().lower())
            index = 5
        else:
            routes.append(element.strip('\n').rstrip().lstrip().lower())

file()
```

1. Use readline() not readlines()
2. you need to strip() the var because it will register the '\n' and consider it not empty.

Comment: doesn't work, i have updated code to give more context

Comment: @Julian see my modified code. Tested will work. included changes made to your code below my modified code

Comment: Still doesnt work mate, not sure why :( do you want me to add the whole code? its long

Comment: @Julian it works on my end with the above code. What was the error on your end?

Comment: dw mate, i fixed it with: if not sys.stdin.isatty():