# Python Read Character by Character without printing

Tags: python, string, readline

Am fairly new to python, We have an interesting situation.

We want to read a char from stdin, store the char, and display another char.

example: the user enters 'c',  the code is expected to save 'c' and print 'v' (instantaneously) 
although `getpass.getpass` saves the input but it print nothing.
Am using Python 2.7 running on mac.

Comment: can you show your whole code in order to help you?

Comment: Thank you Jaay, the below solution by John helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is to "disable echo" in the terminal (aka TTY).  Once you have these keywords, searching for solutions becomes a lot easier.  Here's one:

[How to turn console echo back on after tty.setcbreak()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757915/how-to-turn-console-echo-back-on-after-tty-setcbreak)

Basically, to disable "echoing" the user's input to the screen, do this:

```
import sys
import termios
import tty

old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())
```

After that you can use the regular functions to read from `stdin` and display whatever you want.  Then to re-enable terminal echo:

```
termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
```

Note that the above assumes you're working on a Unix-like system.