# Prompt for user input using python asyncio.create_server instance

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm learning about python 3 asyncio library, and I've run into a small issue. I'm trying to adapt the EchoServer example from the python docs to prompt for user input rather than just echo what the client sends.

I thought it would be as easy as just adding a call to input(), but of course input() will block until there is user input which causes the problems.

Ideally I would like to continue receiving data from the client even when the server has nothing to "say". Somewhat like a chat client where each connection is chatting with the server. I'd like to be able to switch to-and-from each individual connection and send input as needed from stdin. Almost like a P2P chat client.

Consider the following modified EchoServer code:

```
import asyncio

class EchoServerClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('Connection from {}'.format(peername))
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        message = data.decode()
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(message))

        reply = input()
        print('Send: {!r}'.format(reply))
        self.transport.write(reply.encode())

        #print('Close the client socket')
        #self.transport.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# Each client connection will create a new protocol instance
coro = loop.create_server(EchoServerClientProtocol, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

# Serve requests until CTRL+c is pressed
print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Close the server
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

How would I go about getting input form stdin on the server side and specify which connection to send it to while still received inputs from the connected clients?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`loop.add_reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.add_reader) schedule a callback to run when data is available on `sys.stdin`, and then use an [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#queue) to pass the stdin data received to your `data_received` method:

```
import sys
import asyncio


def got_stdin_data(q):
    asyncio.ensure_future(q.put(sys.stdin.readline()))

class EchoServerClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
   def connection_made(self, transport):
       peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
       print('Connection from {}'.format(peername))
       self.transport = transport

   def data_received(self, data):
       message = data.decode()
       print('Data received: {!r}'.format(message))
       fut = asyncio.ensure_future(q.get())
       fut.add_done_callback(self.write_reply)

   def write_reply(self, fut):
       reply = fut.result()
       print('Send: {!r}'.format(reply))
       self.transport.write(reply.encode())

       #print('Close the client socket')
       #self.transport.close()

q = asyncio.Queue()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.add_reader(sys.stdin, got_stdin_data, q)
# Each client connection will create a new protocol instance
coro = loop.create_server(EchoServerClientProtocol, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

# Serve requests until CTRL+c is pressed
print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Close the server
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

The only tricky bit is how we call the `Queue.put`/`Queue.get` methods; both of them are coroutines, which can't be called using `yield from` in the callback or the `Protocol` instance methods. Instead, we just schedule them with the event loop using [`asyncio.ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future), and then use the `add_done_callback` method to handle the reply we retrieve from the `get()` call.

Note: `asyncio.ensure_future` was introduced in Python 3.4.4. Prior to that, the method was called [`asyncio.async`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.async). Additionally, Python 3.7 introduced [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task), which is now the preferred method.

Comment: I suspected that I needed to use a queue like this, but wasn't sure how to implement. Thank you for the great response! It works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the other answers are good. besides, python3.7+ comes, I think it could be more simple:

```
   class AInput():
      def __init__(self):
          self.q = asyncio.Queue()

      async def out(self, prompt='input:'):
          print(prompt)
          await self.q.put(sys.stdin.readline().strip())

      async def input(self):
          tasks = [self.out(), self.q.get()]
          res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
          return res[1]


  async def demo():
      ain = AInput()
      txt = await ain.input()
      print(f"got: {txt}")

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      asyncio.run(demo())
```

Comment: Sadly, if you call in the same thread `sys.stdin.readline()`, your other coroutines will not run because the loop will be stuck waiting for data arriving in sys.stdin.