# Python pre-completed/modifieable input

Tags: python, input

I'm wondering if there's a way to make user edit some input.
I have tried:

```
sys.stdin.write("Foo bar")
input()
```

And expected this behaviour:

```
<< Foo bar
```

The user will edit the string "Foo bar" (e.g. "Foo bar baz"), press enter and the `input` should return the edited string (e.b. "Foo bar baz").

It's something like "editable prompt".

Is there a way to do it?

**EDIT:**  I'm running on OS X, but I would like to support other platforms too.

Comment: @Slayer OP wants something different - to be able to actually present a prompt that can be edited, rather than get a default value from the user.

Comment: Functions like `input()` or `raw_input()` block (don't let other code run) until they finish, so you can't write to the stream programmatically at the same time as other functions. You want [nonblocking console input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408560/python-nonblocking-console-input) that lets you suspend, write to console, and then have user do something with that write. If you can provide specifics about the platform, we can probably help more.