# How can I quit the loop when I want?

Tags: python, loops, opencv, iteration

I working with `R-Pi` and `cam`. I have made code that iterate procedure over an hour.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

ret, frame = cam0.read()
timecheck = time.time()
future = 60
runNo = 0
while ret:
    if time.time() >= timecheck:
        ret, frame = cam0.read()
        #Do something here

        timecheck = time.time()+future
        runNo=runNo+1

        if(runNo> 60):
            break
    else:
        ret = cam0.grab()

#save log as .txt file
with open("acc_list.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(acc_list))
```

But sometimes, it takes less than hour to finish work. I want to quit  the iteration before `runNo` get to `60`. Because I have to save `acc_list.txt` file, I can't just shut the program down.

If it was video streaming, I would use this:

```
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```

But I have encountered errors while modifying this to my code.

Is there nice way to do this?

Comment: How do you know that the work is finished?

Comment: @zwer It is installed in manufacturing machine. Human can judge if it is finished. Finished condition is hardly detected by `cam image`. But my question is that How can I break the loop in running `python shell` manually. For example, typing `q` button to quit the loop in video streaming.

Comment: Can you post the errors you are getting?

Comment: I don't know python well but you should search for something like 'python keyboard input non blocking' e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408560/python-nonblocking-console-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of possible approaches, some are cleaner and some are dirtier :-)

In no particular order, here are some. I will probably add code for them as I find spare time to explain them properly.

---

**Method 1 - Use a *sentinel* file**

An easy (and *"hacky"*) way to do this is to check inside the loop for the existence of a file called `stop`. Then in the shell/Terminal, just do:

```
touch stop
```

and the program will exit. If you happen to use `bash`, you can just type:

```
> stop
```

Remember to delete the file called `stop` at the beginning and end of your program.

I am no Python programmer but this works:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import os
from time import sleep

# Remove any sentinel "stop" files from previous runs
def CleanUp():
    try:
        os.remove('stop')
    except:
        pass

CleanUp()
runNo=0
while True:
    print("Running...")
    sleep(1)
    if runNo>60 or os.path.exists('stop'):
        break
    runNo=runNo+1

print("Writing results")
CleanUp()
```

---

**Method 2 - Use a second thread**

Another way to do it is to start a second thread that does a blocking read from the terminal, and when the user enters something, it sets a flag which the main thread checks on each iteration through its loop the same as it checks `runNo`.

This demonstrates:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import threading
import os
from time import sleep

ExitRequested=False

def InputHandlerThread():
    global ExitRequested
    s=input('Press Enter/Return to exit\n')
    print("Exit requested")
    ExitRequested=True

# Start user input handler - start as daemon so main() can exit without waiting
t=threading.Thread(target=InputHandlerThread,daemon=True)
t.start()

runNo=0
while True:
    print('runNo: {}'.format(runNo))
    sleep(1)
    if runNo>60 or ExitRequested:
        break
    runNo=runNo+1

print("Writing results")
```

This may not work best with OpenCV because the `imshow()` function somehow uses spare time (given as the *milliseconds* parameter) in the `waitKey()` function to update the screen. You will see this if you call `imshow()` without any following `waitKey()` - nothing will appear on the screen.

So, if you are using `imshow()` you must use `waitKey()` and that will interfere with reading the keyboard in the second thread. If that's the case, use one of the other methods.

---

**Method 3 - Write results incrementally**

A third way to do it is to open your results file **for append** inside the loop and add each new result as it comes available rather than waiting till the end.

I don't know enough about your algorithm to know if this is a possibility for you.

I'm still no Python programmer, but this works:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import os
from time import sleep

runNo=0
while True:
    print("Running...")
    # Append results to output file
    with open("results.txt", "a") as results:
        results.write("Result {}\n".format(runNo))
    sleep(1)
    if runNo>60:
        break
    runNo=runNo+1
```

---

**Method 4 - Use a signal**

A fourth way to do it is to set up a signal handler and when it receives the signal it sets a flag which the main loop checks on every iteration. Then in the terminal you use:

```
pkill -SIGUSR1 yourScript.py
```

See [documentation on signals.](http://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html)

Here is some working code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import signal
import os
from time import sleep

def handler(signum,stack):
    print("Signal handler called with signal ",signum)
    global ExitRequested
    ExitRequested=True

ExitRequested=False

# Install signal handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1,handler)


runNo=0
while True:
    print('runNo: {} Stop program with: "kill -SIGUSR1 {}"'.format(runNo,os.getpid()))
    sleep(1)
    if runNo>60 or ExitRequested:
        break
    runNo=runNo+1

print("Writing results")
```

**Sample Output**

```
runNo: 0 Stop program with: "kill -SIGUSR1 16735"
runNo: 1 Stop program with: "kill -SIGUSR1 16735"
runNo: 2 Stop program with: "kill -SIGUSR1 16735"
runNo: 3 Stop program with: "kill -SIGUSR1 16735"
runNo: 4 Stop program with: "kill -SIGUSR1 16735"
runNo: 5 Stop program with: "kill -SIGUSR1 16735"
runNo: 6 Stop program with: "kill -SIGUSR1 16735"
runNo: 7 Stop program with: "kill -SIGUSR1 16735"
Signal handler called with signal  30
Writing results
```

---

**Discussion**

YMMV, but my feeling is that Method 3 is the cleanest, and that Method 1 is the biggest hack. Method 2 is probably closest to what you asked for and I did Method 4 (and all the others, in fact) so I could learn something.

If any real Python programmers have any comments, I'd be happy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

you can put in the loop:

```
 if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

this will let you exit when hitting q.