# How could I read a console input without blocking?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was already thinking about using something like

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    # do stuff
```

but I think that's blocking. Would there be an easy implementation to just run a function to get a line from stdin without stopping all asyncronous operations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408560/python-nonblocking-console-input does this answers your question?

Comment: not quite, since that implementation only allows to check single button presses