# Terminate loop after a certain amount of time

Tags: python, timer

I am trying to write a program that will measure a user's typing speed however I cannot get the loop where the user inputs to terminate when the time is up. I want the loop to stop as soon as the time is finished.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
text = 'Hello My name is matthew'

def some_function(duration):
    end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=duration)
    while datetime.now() < end_time:
       answer = input('Type the following: ' + text + '\n\n')

duration = int(input('How long do you want to test yourself: '))

some_function(duration)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `input()` is blocking. The rest of the code isn't executed until the user submits their input by pressing enter. You should check out this [thread for non-blocking console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408560/non-blocking-console-input)