# How to execute an if else statement in while loop without making the while loop stop?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Im trying to make a countdown timer with the feature to reset/stop/pause/resume. I tried implementing an if/elif/else statement to check for user input letter within the while loop while it continues looping. However, the loop stops running when the conditional statement executes. How do I implement my intended functionality into the code?

code:

```
 import time
 import datetime

 def timeinput():
  # Inputs for hours, minutes, seconds on timer
  h = input("Enter the time in hours: ")
  m = input("Enter the time in minutes: ")
  s = input("Enter the time in seconds: ")
  countdown(int(h), int(m), int(s))

# Create class that acts as a countdown
 def countdown(h, m, s):
  # Print options for user to do
  print("Press w to reset \nPress s to stop \nPress a to pause \nPress d to resume")

  # Calculate the total number of seconds
  total_seconds = h * 3600 + m * 60 + s

  # While loop that checks if total_seconds reaches zero
  # If not zero, decrement total time by one second
  while total_seconds > 0:

    # Timer represents time left on countdown
    timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds = total_seconds)
    
    # Prints the time left on the timer
    print(timer, end="\r")
    
    # Delays the program one second
    time.sleep(1)

    # Reduces total time by one second
    total_seconds -= 1
    user=input()
    
    if user=="w":
      total_seconds=0
      print("Timer will now reset")
      timeinput()

   print("Bzzzt! The countdown is at zero seconds!")

  timeinput()
```

result:
[outcome of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guypf.png)

As shown in the provided image, the loop stops at 20 secs. My intended action here was for the countdown to continue until the user presses the W key, which shall then reset the countdown back to its original set time at initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soo, I'm also kinda new to programming and python so I don't exactly how to make a timer with that functionality. What is happening is that when you use the `input()` function the code stops and waits for the user input.

I know you can use some libraries, like **pygame**, in order to check for user input inside the loop without stopping it, but without one I'm not sure how to do it.

You can also use the module **keyboard**, that comes inside python, and I think is great for the problem you shared. Check this post [How to detect key presses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/how-to-detect-key-presses)

Answer (score 1):

The command `input()` is blocking. It waits until it get something from the console. Maybe take a look at this post and try to implement a non blocking version of input. [Non-blocking console input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408560/non-blocking-console-input)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `input` is blocking - that is, it will stop the execution until the user presses < enter> .

Antique running environments, on 8 bit computers, using Basic, could check "what the user is pressing right now", without waiting for a confirmation with "enter" using the `inkey` command.

In Python programs running on terminal, terminedia, a 3rdy party library, implements `inkey()` as it was - but it needs the terminal input to be reconfigured for which it provides a "keyboard" context manager.

You can then run almost the same code you have -just install terminedia in your Python environment with "pip install terminedia"

```
import terminedia as TM

...

 def countdown(h, m, s):
  ...
  while total_seconds > 0:

    # Timer represents time left on countdown
    timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds = total_seconds)
    
    # Prints the time left on the timer
    print(timer, end="\r")
    
    with TM.keyboard:
        # Delays the program one second
        time.sleep(1)

        # Reduces total time by one second
        total_seconds -= 1
        user=TM.inkey()
        
    if user=="w":
      total_seconds=0
      print("Timer will now reset")
      timeinput()

   print("Bzzzt! The countdown is at zero seconds!")

  timeinput()
```

(disclaimer: I am terminedia author)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but i already solved the issue i was facing using pygame suggested in one of the earlier answers. However i did gain new insight through what you suggested. I shall try it out too.

Comment: Yes - pygame has teh same functionality of non-blocking keyboard read - the drawback in thsio case is that it can only read the keyboard events on the window it creates - which lacks a buffered text output with scrolling. If you can rewrite you app for displaying text in pygame window, though, you can add mouse support and a lot of awesome stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Taking inputs from the answers received here and subsequent follow-up questions on stack overflow and Reddit, this question has been solved using pygame. I'll provide the link below for future reference to this question.

[problem solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/vg4bhn/while_loop_ignoring_pygame_keypress_commands/)