# Python non-blocking input

Tags: python, input, nonblocking

I have an app, which has to make a get request to my API every 4 seconds to stay authorized. My issue is, it uses a whole lot of `input()` which is blocking the thread to make the request. I tried to write a whole module to combat this, but it is still blocking. I have spent so long trying to get a non-blocking input. I have tried almost everything on SO. Here is the class I wrote for non-blocking input. (it has a function `nbput()` that functions almost entirely like python's `input()`)

````py
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key
import threading
import sys
from functools import partial

uinput = ''
lastKey = ''
modifierKey = ''


class NonBlockingInput:
    arg0 = ''

    def __init__(self):
        global listener
        listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.on_press, on_release=self.on_release)
        print('1')

    def on_press(self, key):
        global lastKey
        global modifierKey
        try:
            sys.stdout.write(key.char)
            lastKey = key.char
        except AttributeError:
            if key == Key.space:
                lastKey = ' '
                sys.stdout.write(' ')
                return
            modifierKey = key

    def on_release(self, key):
        pass

    def nbinput(self, prompt):
        global uinput
        global listener
        global lastKey
        global modifierKey
        global arg0
        listener.start()
        sys.stdout.write(prompt)
        while True:
            if modifierKey == Key.enter:
                sys.stdout.write('\n')
                value_returned = partial(self.retrieved_data_func, arg0)
                break
            elif modifierKey == Key.backspace:
                spaceString = ''
                for _ in range(0, len(uinput)):
                    spaceString += ' '
                uinput = uinput[:-1]
                sys.stdout.write('\r')
                sys.stdout.write(spaceString)
                sys.stdout.write('\r')
                sys.stdout.write(uinput)
                modifierKey = ''
            else:
                uinput += lastKey
                lastKey = ''

    def retrieved_data_func(self):
        arg0 = 0
        return arg0


def nbput(prompt=''):
    global collectionThread
    nonBlockingInput = NonBlockingInput()
    collectionThread = threading.Thread(nonBlockingInput.nbinput(prompt))
    collectionThread.start()
    return NonBlockingInput.retrieved_data_func()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(nbput())```
````

Comment: Do your API requests in a separate thread.  Normal `input()`s in the main thread will work just fine.

Comment: You say you have tried nearly everything on SO, but have you tried the top result [Non-blocking console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408560/non-blocking-console-input)?

Comment: @jasonharper I have had it like this since I implemented the API into the app.

Comment: @Grismar I have, this led me to pynput, which is essentially the same thing but cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

All that plumbing seems to get in the way of something that's not that complicated:

```
from time import sleep
from pynput import keyboard


def key_press(key):
    print(f'Pressed {key}')


def api_call():
    print('Making API call...')


listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=key_press)
listener.start()


while True:
    api_call()
    sleep(4)
```

This script "calls an API" once every 4 seconds, while handling user input as it is coming in. It uses `pyinput` as you are, so it should work on whatever platform you're on.

Since the 'API call' here is just a print statement, nothing fancy is needed, but you could of course make the call asynchronously as well. The `sleep(4)` is just there to simulate 4 seconds of otherwise blocking activity.

You responded that you wanted it all in a class, which makes some sense in avoiding globals, but it's not a class you'd want to instance more than once (or even once).

Here's an example that seems to do what you want while avoiding some of the complexity:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from pynput import keyboard
import winsound
try:
    import msvcrt
except ImportError:
    msvcrt = None
    import termios


class NBI:
    text = ''
    listener = None

    @classmethod
    def start(cls):
        if cls.listener is None:
            cls.listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=cls.key_press)
            cls.listener.start()
        else:
            raise Exception('Cannot start NBI twice.')

    @staticmethod
    def flush_input():
        if msvcrt is not None:
            while msvcrt.kbhit():
                msvcrt.getch()
        else:
            termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)

    @classmethod
    def key_press(cls, key):
        if key == keyboard.Key.enter:
            sys.stdout.write('\n')
            cls.flush_input()
            cls.listener.stop()
            cls.listener = None
        if key == keyboard.Key.backspace:
            cls.text = cls.text[:-1]
            sys.stdout.write('\b \b')
            sys.stdout.flush()
        elif hasattr(key, 'char'):
            cls.text += key.char
            sys.stdout.write(key.char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            cls.flush_input()


def api_call():
    winsound.Beep(440, 200)  # "API call"


NBI.start()
while NBI.listener:
    api_call()
    for _ in range(4):
        sleep(1)
        if not NBI.listener:
            break


print(f'You entered: {NBI.text}')
```

Comment: Sorry, I worded my post wrong. The code I provided is the class I wrote to get non-blocking input. I updated the main post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I create the authThread, and then call main.