# How to run both input() and buttons() at the same time? Preferably with no libraries

Tags: python, tkinter, input

How to run both input() and buttons() at the same time? Preferably with no libraries.

```
from threading import*
from asyncio import*
from multiprocessing import*
from time import*
from tkinter import*

yhealth = 0

def onButton(n):
    global m
    if n == 0:
        return m
    else:
        m = n
        return n

def buttons():
    sleep(1)
    main = Tk()
    main.geometry('250x50')
    Att = Button(main, text = 'Attack', command = lambda:(onButton(1), main.destroy()), fg = 'red')
    Att.pack(side = LEFT)
    Reg = Button(main, text = 'Regen', command = lambda:(onButton(2), main.destroy()), fg = 'red')
    Reg.pack(side = LEFT)
    Rock = Button(main, text = 'Attack', command = lambda:(onButton(3), main.destroy()))
    Rock.pack(side = RIGHT)
    Shield = Button(main, text = 'Shield', command = lambda:(onButton(4), main.destroy()), fg = 'blue')
    Shield.pack(side = RIGHT)
    main.mainloop()

def inputchoose():
    global chosenmove
    chosenmove = 0
    chosenmove = int(input('Choose 1/2/3/4'))
    if chosenmove == (1 or 2 or 3 or 4):
        return chosenmove
    return(chosenmove)

def movetell():
    global yhealth
    ymove = 0
    inputchoose(), buttons() ##this part doesn't work, it waits for input to close, and only then turns on #buttons
    while True:
        if buttons() != None:
            ymove = str(buttons())
            print('lol')
            break
        if inputchoose() != None:
            print('lol.')
            ymove = str(inputchoose())
            break
```

#remaking the entire code in general would be nice as well, tysm

I've tried many variations, but none of it works, so I'm hopeless.

Comment: Why "ultra challenge, complex code", is it supposed to be a click bait ? It does not match the question.

Comment: because it's an Ultra challenge for me xD that's not for everyone ikr. I will edit the name

Comment: Add `Entry` widget on `buttons()` function.

Comment: Instead of this int(input('Choose 1/2/3/4')). then add Label widget.... Label(main, text='Choose 1/2/3/4') then use Entry.get()

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want a keyboard input listener but have the buttons active at the same time as an alternative input.

`input()` will always block the thread, so if you want several threads you need to create them : https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

You will find examples on SO searching for "python non-blocking input" (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57387909/2197181)

Comment: unfortunately using Thread doesn't work with buttons as running buttons as a Thread makes them unusable, because they don't respond after pressing on them without making them block the entire thread. Input also doesn't work with Thread. Does that mean I have to go for the second link?

Comment: The second link is an example of input working in a thread, so one of these statements must be wrong.

Comment: Buttons already have a listener in their own thread, so you should not add one yourself. It is the kb input you have to wrap.