How to read character input, in a terminal, without blocking, in Python?
I have a loop that I need to keep looping. Meanwhile I want to know if the user has pressed a key within the loop, but I don't want to have to wait before continuing.
This also needs to work in a terminal session.
Libraries like readchar and SSHkeyboard work in a terminal session, but block the loop until a key has been pressed.
Libraries like pynput can do it without blocking the loop, but they aren't reading input from a shell, they are monitoring the system itself.
What is a simple way to do this?

what have you actually tried ? is the read within this looping construct or completely outwith, what action is needed when a key press is detected .... ?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/2408560/536262- Solved it for me when I had the same problem bot mac and windows
